# Service layer and repositories performance question

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

i have multiple repositories in my project for different entities and each has it's own datacontext (which comes from a base class for my repositories).

In my service layer, there are many times that the business logic requires me to add/edit objects in multiple repositories (hence inturn using different DataContext).

So when i end up doing .SaveContext on multiple repositories. Which seems like a bad thing to do as ideally i should be able to hit Save on one context and one ado.net call to the DB should perform all the tasks.

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look at using the [Unit of Work pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) with your repositories, as it allows your multiple repositories to take part in a single logical transaction.

there are plenty of blog posts around the net about how to do this, including;

- [Using Repository and Unit of Work patterns with Entity Framework 4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx)
- [ASP.NET MVC, DataContext and The Unit of Work Pattern](http://iridescence.no/post/ASPNET-MVC-DataContext-and-The-Unit-of-Work-Pattern.aspx)
- [The Unit Of Work Pattern And Persistence Ignorance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd882510.aspx)

Also here is a [good tutorial](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) walking through using MVC and EF with a Unit of Work + Repository pattern.

As here is a nice diagram explaining how it works;

[image]

Comment: Sweet .. thanks for so many awesome examples. I didnt know the name of the pattern and was exactly what was missing from my architecture. Now that i implemented it in one sitting of 4 hours straight.. It is clean as a whistle and much faster!